# Кодировка или IO тонкости

Tags: java

Есть такой код, который считывает файл

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/home/roman/sudo");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
DataInput dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
```

Потом чтоб преобразовать его в правильный примитив я хочу воспользоваться DataInput интерфейсом, но я не понимаю почему результаты разные

```
System.out.println((char)dis.readByte());
```

вывод: h

```
System.out.println(dis.readChar());
```

вывод: 瑴

```
System.out.println((char)dis.readInt());
```

вывод: ⼯

содержимое файла такое : http://dl.goo

Comment: @romashechka, вы как-то криво вставили ссылку на файл.

Comment: то не ссылка на файл, то содержимое файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим исходный код методов:

```
public final byte readByte() throws IOException {
    int ch = in.read();
    if (ch < 0)
        throw new EOFException();
    return (byte)(ch);
}

public final char readChar() throws IOException {
    int ch1 = in.read();
    int ch2 = in.read();
    if ((ch1 | ch2) < 0)
        throw new EOFException();
    return (char)((ch1 << 8) + (ch2 << 0));
}

public final int readInt() throws IOException {
    int ch1 = in.read();
    int ch2 = in.read();
    int ch3 = in.read();
    int ch4 = in.read();
    if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
        throw new EOFException();
    return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
}
```

byte 1 байт, char 2 байта, int 4 байта. Естесственно будут разные результаты.

Answer (score 1):

`InputStream` и `OutputStream` в общем случае работают с байтами, вы же хотите работать с набором символов. Для решения ваше задачи нужно использовать классы `InputStreamReader` (который правильным образом преобразовывает байты в символы) и `OutputSreamWriter` (который правильно преобразовывает символы в байты).

**Обновление**

Разница между примитивным `char` и ссылочным `Char` такая же, как и разница между любым другим примитивом и его оберткой. И в том и в другом случае char представляется двумя байтами в Java, а вот в обычном текстовом  файле представление отличается. В Unicode символ может быть представлен разным кол-вом байтов и Reader'ы знают, как с этим работать.

Comment: A data input stream lets an application read primitive Java data types from an underlying input stream in a machine-independent way

Comment: @romashechka и что?

Comment: Может, я, конечно, заблуждаюсь в чем то, но я же считываю примитивный char. Значит DataInputStream тоже можно использовать.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: так а для чего тогда сущуствует данная библиотека? DataInputStream/DataOuputStream. В каких случая ее использовать?

Comment: @romashechka, обратите внимание на слова

     An application uses a data output stream to write data that can later be read by a data input stream. 

в [описании DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)

Comment: Какие это случаи?